# A relational query, not sure how to build it with EXISTS

Tags: mysql

```
carts
id user_id

cart_proucts
id cart_id product_id price

products
much details about the product...
```

So this is some easier form of my table structure currently. I have a list of product Id, that I need to check against a User if he has them  or not, I know that by looking at cart_products which a cart belongs to a user, as the relationship described above. If he has  I should retrieve that "User" and information he contains. But I also need to check if the price range of the product, i.e. the product must not be lower than 500 for i.e. The price column in the cart_products...

How can I easiest build this sql? I am thinking of JOINS and some use of EXISTS or IN perhaps?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE products.id IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM Users 
INNER JOIN carts on carts.user_id = Users.id
INNER JOIN cart_products on carts.id = carts_products.cart_id
WHERE cart_products.price > X and cart_products.price < Y
AND cart_products.product_id IN (LIST OF PRODUCT IDS)
```

The INNER JOIN will only join where there is a `carts` and `carts_products` entry that fits.

===EDIT===

To return a single user you can either alter the first line to be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.* FROM Users
INNER JOIN carts on carts.user_id = Users.id
INNER JOIN cart_products on carts.id = carts_products.cart_id
WHERE cart_products.price > X and cart_products.price < Y
AND cart_products.product_id IN (LIST OF PRODUCT IDS TO INCLUDE)
AND cart_products.product_id NOT IN (LIST OF PRODUCT IDS TO EXCLUDE)
```

OR use an IN with a sub query:

```
SELECT u.* from Users u WHERE u.id IN 
(
    SELECT Users.id FROM Users 
    INNER JOIN carts on carts.user_id = Users.id
    INNER JOIN cart_products on carts.id = carts_products.cart_id
    WHERE cart_products.price > X and cart_products.price < Y
    AND cart_products.product_id IN (LIST OF PRODUCT IDS)
)
```

I *THINK* the first option might be slightly more optimal, but it's entirely possible they could be optimised by the query planner to be the same.  You will have to run some benchmarks to be sure.

===EDIT 2===

So Now I think you are asking for an INTERSECTION?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.* FROM Users
INNER JOIN carts on carts.user_id = Users.id
INNER JOIN cart_products on carts.id = carts_products.cart_id
WHERE cart_products.price > X and cart_products.price < Y
AND cart_products.product_id IN (LIST OF PRODUCT IDS TO INCLUDE)

INTERSECT

SELECT DISTINCT Users.* FROM Users
INNER JOIN carts on carts.user_id = Users.id
INNER JOIN cart_products on carts.id = carts_products.cart_id
WHERE cart_products.price > X and cart_products.price < Y
AND cart_products.product_id NOT IN (LIST OF PRODUCT IDS TO EXCLUDE)
```

Which I think might also be the same as...

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.* FROM Users
INNER JOIN carts on carts.user_id = Users.id
INNER JOIN cart_products on carts.id = carts_products.cart_id
WHERE cart_products.price > X and cart_products.price < Y
AND cart_products.product_id IN (LIST OF PRODUCT IDS TO INCLUDE)

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT Users.* FROM Users
INNER JOIN carts on carts.user_id = Users.id
INNER JOIN cart_products on carts.id = carts_products.cart_id
WHERE cart_products.price > X and cart_products.price < Y
AND cart_products.product_id IN (LIST OF PRODUCT IDS TO EXCLUDE)
```

Not sure which SQL implementations allow EXCEPT, but an alternative is to use a LEFT JOIN as described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)#EXCEPT_operator

===EDIT 3===

```
SELECT u.* from Users u WHERE u.id IN 
(
    SELECT Users.id FROM Users 
    INNER JOIN carts on carts.user_id = Users.id
    INNER JOIN cart_products on carts.id = carts_products.cart_id
    WHERE cart_products.price > X and cart_products.price < Y
    AND cart_products.product_id IN (LIST OF PRODUCT IDS TO INCLUDE)
)
AND u.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT Users.id FROM Users 
    INNER JOIN carts on carts.user_id = Users.id
    INNER JOIN cart_products on carts.id = carts_products.cart_id
    WHERE cart_products.price > X and cart_products.price < Y
    AND cart_products.product_id IN (LIST OF PRODUCT IDS TO EXCLUDE)
)
```

Comment: It kinda works, however I got multiple results back as I suppose it should be, but isn't it possibl to have each "cart" stored, instead of having like 10 results with same cart id back because of multiple products in cart_products. Because what I really want is to just return if the User actually have it in his cart, not the actual cart itself.

Comment: The first one is almost perfect, however I am trying to add "NOT IN" as well, but the User is returned anyway, assume a User has cart_products.product_id has 4 and 5, If he has both I don't want to return him

SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM users
INNER JOIN carts on carts.id = users.id
INNER JOIN cart_products on carts.id = cart_products.cart_id
WHERE users.total_sum > 200
AND cart_products.product_id IN (4) AND cart_products.product_id NOT IN (5)

Comment: I'm not certain I understand you? Perhaps you could edit your question with the extra details?  It sounds like you want to make use of UNION, INTERSECT AND EXCEPT, but i'm not sure exactly what your are after:  check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)

Comment: How can I perform a query that only grabs the cart_id from cart_products where it has product_id 5 and not product_id 4, if i can perform that query I can simply split up the queries above...
So lets say if it has a row contaning 5 its good, but if it also has a row with product_id 4, lets not grab it

Comment: Yeah, that might be it, but it gives me a syntax error. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERSECT SELECT DISTINCT Users.* FRO

Comment: I expect mysql doesn't support the INTERSECT keyword then...  I'll do another edit with an answer that should also work ;)

Comment: That's a heavy query with 2 subqueries and joins. I would advise optimizing this query by moving conditions to the `INNER JOIN` so that products with wrong price/id won't be included in the temporary join-table that is then put through the `WHERE` condition: `INNER JOIN cart_products ON cart_products.cart_id = carts.id AND cart_products.price > X AND cart_products.price < Y AND cart_products.product_id IN (LIST OF PRODUCT IDS TO INCLUDE)`

Comment: @funkwurm I'm sure there a many optimisations (Including that one you've suggested) that could be made - I should point out that this was not intended to be an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` `u`
JOIN `carts` `c` ON (`u`.`id` = `c`.`user_id`)
JOIN `cart_products` `cp` ON (`cp`.`cart_id` = `c`.`id`)
JOIN `products` `p` ON (`p`.`id` = `cp`.`product_id` AND `p`.`price` > `cp`.`price`)
WHERE `p`.`id` IN (...);
```

Comment: No need to join on products - carts_products has the price in it

Comment: I don't quite get the last part of his question tho : "the product must not be lower than 500 for i.e. The price column in the cart_products"